async loop through childNodes
I want to sequentially perform operations to HTML elements (like sequential typewriting machine)
I read this question on how to loop through childNodes.
But I also read that we cannot use forEach for async operations.
This is the code that so far doesn't wait for one sequence to launch the next.
<script>
    const typewriter = (node) => {
        var fullText = '';
        node.childNodes.forEach(async (child) => {
            if (child.nodeType === 1) {
                fullText = child.textContent;
                child.textContent = '';

                await type(child, fullText);
            }
        });

        function type(node, fullText) {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                if (node.textContent.length >= fullText.length) {
                    resolve();
                    return;
                }

                node.textContent = fullText.substring(0, node.textContent.length + 1);
                var timeout = setTimeout(type, 100, node, fullText);
            });
        }

        return {
            destroy() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            }
        };
    };
</script>

<span use:typewriter><slot /></span>


Note : it is a svelte component but I'm not sure it has something to do with the issue
Thanks !

Use an async function with a for loop that uses await.

So have you tried to use the solutions from the Q&A you've found?

Btw your type function is broken, it never resolves the originally returned promise - notice each type() call creates a new one. I would suggest you only use a delay method where you wrap a single setTimeout in a promise, then use only async/await (with a for or while loop over the fulltext).

Thx ! I think I see what you mean but I'm not sure how to implement the promise thing ? Is it ok performance wise to have a promise each 10ms ? Maybe you can write the code in an answer so I can check if it works ?

switch to "for of" which does support await instead of foreach.
const typewriter = async (node) => {
  for (const child of node.childNodes) {
           ...
           await type(child, fullText);
          }
        }


Thx ! I tried this but I didn't have the const statement so it was working. So now this works but the texts are still appearing in parallel. Maybe check the comments from Bergi ?
